# Use a tag at the end of a html link, like; edit.php?id=0 and get the 0 picked up as a variable in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a page printing from a sql server.
And ive made a page to edit one and one line. (edit.php) With a textbox and submit, able to update the sql database.

I want to place a link to the editpage from each line printed from the sql server. Each line has an id, and i thougt maybe i could link to edit.php?id=1

And this way set a php variable to the value 1. load line 1 into the form. and write to line one when i save the form.

how can i "pick up" the idnumber ?
is there a clearly better way to do it?

Comment: [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), and have a read of [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) which is a pretty fundamental feature of PHP that you need to understand for working with web applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$_GET['id']` in `edit.php` file to retreive the `id` parameter value